# Perforce: integrate overwritten change back in

Tags: merge, perforce

A colleague committed a change without resolving my recent code changes. So my bug fix was overwritten.

What I want to do is the equivalent of an integrate between my previous change and the latest change. but running:

```
p4 integ //depot/folder/file.c@123 //depot/folder/file.c
```

gives me this error:

```
//depot/folder/file.c@123 - all revision(s) already integrated.
```

What's the best way to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Perforce point of view, your changelist has already been integrated (even if it has been overwritten later).

To force the integration of your file again, you must use the `-f` option :

```
p4 integrate -f //depot/folder/file.c@=123 //depot/folder/file.c
```

Source :

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html

> -f
>
> Force the integration on all revisions of fromFile and toFile, even if
>   some revisions have been integrated in the past. Best used with a
>   revision range.

Comment: In the specific case of the original question, the "Best used with a revision range" would be: `//depot/folder/file.c@123,123`, or `//depot/folder/file.c@=123`, so that exactly that one changelist is re-integrated.